# how to get jquery anchor href value

Tags: jquery, anchor

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.change_status").click(function(){
       var status_id = $("a").val();
       alert(status_id); 
       return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="?status=5" class="change_status">Aminul</a><br/>
<a href="?status=25" class="change_status">Arif</a><br/>
<a href="?status=15" class="change_status">Sharif</a><br/>
```

I need `status_id` and for some reason my anchor tag is dynamic. I can't use id or make class name dynamic. I think, I need to use `$this` to get my value.

Comment: this is not for an #anchor but a ?query

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This one is simple :

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("a.change_status").click(function(){
           var status_id = $(this).attr('href').split('=');
           alert(status_id[1]); 
           return false;
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NmzRV/

Answer (score 5):

```
var status_id= $(this).attr("href").match(/status=([0-9]+)/)[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').attr('href');
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 3):

You have two separate issues here... first you need to find the actual clicked link using `this` and then find the value of that href attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.change_status").click(function() {
        var status_id = parseURL($(this).attr("href"));
        alert(status_id);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also, because javascript doesn't have a way to pull URL parameters, you must write a function (in the example `parseURL`) in which to find the value of the variable "status":

```
function parseURL(theLink) {
    return decodeURI((RegExp('status=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(theLink) || [, null])[1]);
}
```

See the following jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZKMwU/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("a.change_status").click(function() { 
      var status_id = $(this).attr("href"); 
      alert(status_id);
      return false;
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.change_status").click(function(){
           var status_id = $(this).attr("href");
           alert(status_id); return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.change_status").click(function(){ 
     var status_id = $(this).attr('href'); 
     alert(status_id); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listItems = $(".nav-dropdown--products .li");
listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
    var product = $(li); 
    alert($('a', this).attr('href'));
});
```