# Get the URL of a link within a div

Tags: jquery, html, href

I want to get the text of the URL that is within a div:

```
<div class="div">
    <a class="link" href="iwanttogetthis">Link Name</a>
</div>
```

This is what I have

```
$('.link').find("href").text();
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do like this $('.link').attr("href")

Comment: I don't immediately know the jQuery, off hand, but the vanilla JS would be something like: `document.querySelector('a.link').getAttribute('href')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get jquery anchor href value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926045/how-to-get-jquery-anchor-href-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) searches for **elements** that are descendants of the selected element.

[`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) extracts the text nodes from the descendants of the selected element.

You want to read [an **attribute** value](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) from the selected element. Its descendants are irrelevant.

```
$(".link").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 2):

`.find()` will not work in your case. You can use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)  jquery method to get any attribute value as shown below.

```
$('.link').attr("href");
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmzRV/635/)